# What is the PEI format?

Tags: file-format, portable-executable, executable-format

I understand that PE is a modified version of COFF, and that PE+ is a modified version of PE with 64 bit support, but what is PEI? Am I correct in saying there is no difference between PE and PEI, and they can be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PEI isn't actually an officially recognized format or term. The PE/COFF standard describes only two formats: PE32 (the 32-bit format) and PE32+ (the 64-bit format). I have heard discussions about PE vs PEI before, but the only place I've ever come across the term PEI is in `libpei`, referenced in the answer by [JEdot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27849556/2646573). And, as quoted in that answer, the `libpei` developers seem to be confused about the terminology themselves, so it really does not make sense to use the term PEI at all.

Moreover, it is not correct that the MS-DOS stub is required to run a PE executable on Windows. It is just commonly embedded for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

> "**The *sole* difference between the pe format and the pei format is
> that the    latter has an MSDOS 2.0 .exe header on the front that
> prints the message    "This app must be run under Windows."** (or some
> such).    (FIXME: Whether that statement is *really* true or not is
> unknown.    Are there more subtle differences between pe and pei
> formats?    For now assume there aren't.  If you find one, then for
> God sakes    document it here!)
>
> The Microsoft docs use the word "image" instead of "executable"
> because    the former can also refer to a DLL (shared library).
> Confusion can arise    because the `i' in` pei' also refers to
> "image".  The `pe' format can    also create images (i.e.
> executables), it's just that to run on a win32    system you need to
> use the pei format."

Source :

> http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gdb/gdb-1515/src/bfd/libpei.h